# Select (dropdown) control in omniscript does not show real data or shows cached data

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, vlocity, omnistudio

I have a select control(dropdown) in omniscript to show list of certain users with below properties.

Option Source: Custom

Source: Apexclass.methodname.

Where 'methodname' is the method in apex class which returns the users and binds the data to the select control.

However it does not show the latest data. it refreshes the data every time when i de-activate  and re-activate the omniscript control. **That means it is showing cached data**.

How to fix this issue so that it shows latest data every time drop down selected?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled across the same behavior.

From the publicly available documentation, it states that the Select Element can be prefilled "dynamically". It also states the following:

> You can populate Select, Multi-select, and Radio elements from a Vlocity Open Interface Custom
> implementation. The values for the element are **obtained during the OmniScript's activation**.

So, it's not really a bug but rather a feature that makes no sense. It would be quite nice if it worked but it is what it is.